# Regex Help for content between two strings (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Hoping someone might help. I have a string formatted like the example below:

```
Lipsum text as part of a paragraph here, yada. |EMBED|{"content":"foo"}|/EMBED|. Yada and the text continues...
```

What I am looking for is a Javascript RegEx to capture the content between the `|EMBED||/EMBED|` 'tags', run a function on that content, and then to replace the entire `|EMBED|...|/EMBED|` string with the return of that function.

The catch is that I may have multiple `|EMBED|` blocks within a larger string. For example:

```
Yabba...|EMBED|{"content":"foo"}|/EMBED|. Dabba-do...|EMBED|{"content":"yo"}|/EMBED|.
```

I need the RegEx to capture and process each `|EMBED|` block separately, since the content contained within will be similar, but unique.

**My initial thought** is that I could just have a RegEx that captures the first iteration of the `|EMBED|` block, and the function which replaces this `|EMBED|` block is either part of a loop or recursion to continuously find the next block and replace it, until no more blocks are found in the string.

...but this seems expensive. Is there a more eloquent way?

Comment: So where are you stuck? Please post the regex you used and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Use a non-greedy quantifier, or use a negative lookahead.

Comment: Why does it have to be an iteration and not a single function call?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I was stuck finding a better solution than the one I proposed. But it seems that a few authors below have given me a really good and potentially less expensive solution than the one I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.replace` to replace a substring found via a regular expression with a modified version of the match [using a mapping function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), e.g.:

```js
var input = 'Yabba...|EMBED|{"content":"foo"}|/EMBED|. Dabba-do...|EMBED|{"content":"yo"}|/EMBED|.'

var output = input.replace(/\|EMBED\|(.*?)\|\/EMBED\|/g, function(match, p1) {
  return p1.toUpperCase()
})

console.log(output) // "Yabba...{"CONTENT":"FOO"}. Dabba-do...{"CONTENT":"YO"}."
```

---

Make sure that you use a non-greedy selector `.*?` to select the content between the delimiters to allow multiple replacements per string.

Comment: This looks the most eloquent. Will test later today or tomorrow (when I can jump back into the project that needs this) and will mark my question resolved if everything works as expected!

Comment: For some reason I needed to use `function(match, p0, p1)` instead of `function(match, p1)` for `p1` to match the content inside my tag, but it worked. Very elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the cod which iterate through the matches of the regex:

```
var str = 'Lipsum text as part of a paragraph here, yada. |EMBED|{"content":"foo"}|/EMBED|. Yada and the text continues...';
var rx = /\|EMBED\|(.*)\|\/EMBED\|/gi;
var match;
while (true)
{
    match = rx.exec(str);
    if (!match)
        break;
    console.log(match[1]); //match[1] is the content between "the tags"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, though I think @Timo's solution below might be an even shorter way to achieve my goal. Appreciate the time you took to write out my looping idea into code!